# Best JavaScript inheritance implementation

Tags: javascript, oop

In JavaScript what sort of inheritance do you favour? The ECMA standard is to use prototype chaining. So I just set the prototype of the object that's doing the inheriting (monkey) to invoke a new instance of the object I want to inherit from (animal):

```
monkey.prototype = new animal();
```

I am aware there are other ways to achieve inheritance. i.e inheriting only the prototype, parasitic inheritance, deep copy, shallow copy.

Can anyone enlighten me and tell me if there is one in particular I should use? One that has benefits that outweigh the other methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theres a lot better article on it here than I could ever write. http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

In general it depends on what you want to achieve. In general though I think duck typing is what is considered best for javascript.

Comment: @elduderino, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: Also see: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: @wes I feel that this method isn't popularly used, though its a interesting read. Mr. Crockford says himself on the page, "I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake."

Comment: This answer was given 6 years ago. It's probably not relevant any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an article that talks about the in and outs of JS inheritance. It's relevant if you're trying to emulate class based inheritance. I don't like Douglas Crockford's approach that tries to stay away from the new keyword. I learned class based inheritance with C++ and Java and find it much easier to think about http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html